# Auto correct algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I want to implement the following in C++:

1) Check whether the given word exists in a dictionary. The dictionary file is a huge file; consider 100MB or 3-4 Million words.

2) Suggest corrections for the incorrect word.

3) Autocomplete feature.

## My Approach

1) I am planning to build a tree so searching will efficient.

2) I am not getting how to implement auto correction feature.

3) I can implement auto complete feature using trees

[image: My tree Image]

What's the best data structure and algorithm to implement all the above features?

Comment: Looks like a trie http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Here is complete solution for the above question https://github.com/msankith/Trie/tree/1.1

Comment: While it works efficiently, I found this to be a rather inefficient solution. Tries are not memory efficient. Also this can only correct spellings for upto one incorrectly spelled alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

I have been working on the same problem. So far the best solution I have come across is using a ternary search tree for auto completion. Ternary Search Trees are more space efficient than tries.
If im unable to find the looked up string in my ternary search tree then I use an already built BK Tree for finding the closest match. BK Tree internally uses Levenshtein distance.
You

Metaphones are also something you might want to explore however I havent gone into the depth of metaphones.

I have a solution in Java for BK TREE + TERNARY SEARCH TREE if you like.

Comment: Do you have implementation for auto-correct or suggestion for wrongly typed words.
I have implemented using brute force .In need of better algorithm

Comment: like I said, use a BK Tree for auto correct. It uses Levenshtein Distance internally. For example, Cabllge would be corrected to cabbage if you allow it to correct at max 2 characters. It will also suggest other possible based on the max Levenshtein distance you allow. It is a much faster implementation than brute force.

Comment: This is exactly what I did too and it works great. Somebody else may consider using SymSplell as a replacement for BK Tree. Note: With BK Tree you can find an exact match if you use a max edit distance equals to 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can do autocomplete by looking at all the strings in a given subtree. Some score to help you pick might help. This works something like if you have "te" you go down that path in the trie and the traverse the entire subtree there to get all the possible endings.

For corrections you need to implement something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance over the tree. You can use the fact that if you processed a given path in the trie, you can reuse the result for all the strings in the subtree rooted at the end of your path.

Comment: How to use "Levenshtein distance" to implement auto correction?

As per my understanding - 
Levenshtein Distance is used to compare given string with list of strings(Dictionary) . but If i go on compare with each string in dictionary, it takes lots of time . 

Is there any better running algorithm exists for the same.

Comment: @Ankith: BK trees are an algorithm which exploits the fact that Levenshtein distance is a metric space, to optimize searching for nearest-neighbors of one string (query) in a set of strings (dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

1) Aside from trees, another interesting method is BWT
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform 
BWT suffix array can be easily used to track words with given prefix.

2) For error correction, modern approach is LHS:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing#LSH_algorithm_for_nearest_neighbor_search

Some links randomly provided by google search:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/efficient-map-data-structure-supporting-approximate-lookup
https://code.google.com/p/likelike/
http://aspguy.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/the-magic-behind-the-google-search/